# GCC with-gxx-include-dir is set to iOS 11.4 simulator

Tags: xcode, development, gcc

I'm trying to compile https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq which requires me to run `autoconf` and then `./configure`. It was working a few days ago, but now this happens:

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/local/bin/ginstall -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/local/bin/gmkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether UID '502' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking whether GID '20' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/Users/rajiv/libzmq/libzmq-4.2.5':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details
```

`config.log` shows:

```
configure:4489: checking whether we are cross compiling
configure:4497: gcc -o conftest    conftest.c  >&5
configure:4501: $? = 0
configure:4508: ./conftest
dyld: mach-o, but built for simulator (not macOS)
./configure: line 4510: 98877 Abort trap: 6           ./conftest$ac_cv_exeext
configure:4512: $? = 134
```

After searching GitHub for a while it seems like something might be wrong with GCC:

```
$ gcc -v

Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.4.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1

Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)

Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0

Thread model: posix

InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

It seems like it's trying to `include` from the iOS 11.4 SDK. How can I change it back to the correct path and how did this change happen? The only things I can think of are that I installed an update for the Xcode Command Line Tools and I may have updated `autoconf` with Homebrew

Comment: I doubt /usr/include/c++/4.2.1 is the correct include that is for an old gcc - Apple does not supply gcc anymore but clang. I wopuld look at ports systems like macports or Homebrew to see how they manage any changes this build needs

Comment: Why have you used a homebrew tag?

Comment: @Mark I had assumed that was the proper directory but really I just want to change it to whatever directory it should be. I'll edit the question accordingly. I added the homebrew tag because I'm not sure if Homebrew influenced this change but I'll remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was seeing a similar issue.

```
$ gcc -v
    Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.4.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
```

In my case, that configuration resulted in includes like `#include <stdlib.h>` referencing the iOS/iPhone simulator platform libraries rather than the macOS libraries. This resulted in my getting errors about the wrong architecture being used when compiling.

The only viable solution I found was to uninstall Xcode (deleting the app from `/Applications`) and [uninstall the command line tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27438457/xcode-6-1-how-to-uninstall-command-line-tools). That and a reboot seemed to resolve this issue in my case.

Comment: Thanks! That worked for me. Not sure what the root cause was, maybe an Xcode update