# wrong with-gxx-include-dir with clang

Tags: terminal, xcode, gcc

my gcc compiler is pointing to an old/missing include directory:

```
(base) ➜  Accounts gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

i.e. this path `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1` doesn't exist.

Any ideas on how to get the correct gxx-include-dir to be recognised please?

Having read [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/329446/gcc-with-gxx-include-dir-is-set-to-ios-11-4-simulator) question I tried:

1. uninstalling command line tools (I didn't have Xcode), rebooting, and reinstalling using `xcode-select --install`
2. installing Xcode and re-installing command line tools.

all of which failed to change the directory.

My brew installs are:

```
(base) ➜  Accounts brew list
autoconf        ilmbase         libomp          openexr         pkg-config      shared-mime-info    zlib
freetype        imagemagick     libpng          openjpeg        pyenv           sqlite
gdbm            jpeg            libtiff         openssl         python          tree
gettext         libde265        libtool         openssl@1.1     rbenv           webp
git         libffi          libyaml         pcre            readline        x265
glib            libheif         little-cms2     pcre2           ruby-build      xz
```

As per request:

```
(pyemma_dev) ➜  myPyEMMA git:(devel) ✗ xcode-select -p
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

I also tried adding

```
export SDKROOT="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk"
```

and the same thing with `MacOSX10.14.sdk` to my .zshrc folder, sourcing it and then retrying. Same error message (except with `10.14` which prompted me to install command line developer tools.

I'm on macOS 10.15.6 (Catalina). I'm also running Conda as well and I know that has messed up unsual things before so I thought I'd mention it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you tell the output of `xcode-select -p`

Comment: Thanks. I've added the output to question.

Comment: Does adding this line `export SDKROOT="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk"` to `~/.bash_profile` or  its zsh equivalent help ? Remember to reopen terminal after saving the file.

Comment: No, it asks me to install command line developer tools, which I declined.  This is the contents of my SDKs folder though: 

> DriverKit19.0.sdk
> MacOSX.sdk
>MacOSX10.15.sdk -> MacOSX.sdk

Comment: well you need to give an existing sdk path :) If you have the Xcode zip  file, just reinstall the app ?

Comment: Yep!  Got that, tried it, reinstalled CLTs but didn't work.  I'll try re-installing Xcode.

Comment: Note your gcc compiler is not gcc it is clang

Comment: Thanks @anki - still no luck. However, whatever value of SDKROOT I give it, it always appends usr/include/c++/4.2.1. The c++/4.2.1 bit never exists though.

Comment: @mmmmmm seems right. there're only two gcc executables `/usr/bin/gcc` & Xcode `Contents/Developer/usr/bin/gcc` both of which are 19 KB. They cannot be compilers. If you need gcc, get it from the official site or build them.

Comment: Thanks folks.  I actually swtiched to  compilers installed through conda and everything worked fine.